# Проблема при сборке проекта на Cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova

Пишу программу на Cordova. Хочу запустить ее в эмуляторе. Для этого в консоли прописал команду:

```
cordova run android
```

При компиляции возникла ошибка

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac/Users/taruk/App/BChat/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/common/logger/LogFragment.java:36: error: package android.support.v4.app does not exist
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Я так понял, что надо что то доставить?

Answer (score 0):

Ваша ошибка:

> error: package android.support.v4.app does not exist

У вас подключен в зависимостях подключен `com.android.support:support-v4:2X.X.X`? Если нет, подключите. Сам Cordova не использую, но гугл выдаёт это: [link](http://npm%20i%20cordova-plugin-android-support-v4).

Похожий вопрос: [android.support.v4.app does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49908072/android-support-v4-app-does-not-exist)

Comment: я тоже уже нашел это решение, но после того, как я добавляю эту строку, мне выдает ошибку ***Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:support-v4:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
Open Android SDK Manager***

Comment: но у меня все установлено - http://joxi.ru/V2VOkM1I0weKxA

Comment: @Diefair куда вы прописали зависимость, в `build.gradle`? Если да, то ошибка говорит, что вы прописали в зависимостях в `build.gralde` на уровне проекта, а надо — на уровне модуля. Или вы используете какие-то кордовские специфические конфигурации для зависимостей?